.NET Aspire : change service url
How to dynamically modify the URL in Aspire Dashboard with query parameters?
Clarifications: this is not about authentication, it's all about URLs in Aspire.
Let's assume that we have .NET 9, an empty default web app and .NET Aspire on top of it.
Background: Each time my website starts it generate unique auth URL. By visiting this URL, we can gain authenticated access to the site.
For example, the URL looks like this:
https://localhost:17061/login?t=4d571ce34e2c5b96ca157179cfe385e8

Whenever the dashboard started, the url should be populated.
Questions

How to replace the default URL in the Aspire dashboard with a new one that includes query parameters every time the application starts?
This should be done while dashboards start.
Imaginary realization:
builder.AddProject<Projects.StarsPayments_Server>("starspayments-server")
       .WithHttpsEndpoint(new Uri("https://localhost:17061/login?t=4d571ce34e2c5b96ca157179cfe385e8"))
       .DisableDefaultEndpoints();

But there is no method WithHttpsEndpoint with Uri parameter.
DisableDefaultEndpoints - should remove https://localhost:17061 from dashboard.

How to make it so that the URL changes in the dashboard every time I click the "Restart Service" button from dashboard? This part of a question is the continuing of 1 question. Whenever the url is set, how to make it dynamic so when press 'Restart' it becomes new URL.
Imaginary realization part 2:
 var urlFromServer = GetUrlFromServer();

 builder.AddProject<Projects.StarsPayments_Server>("MYAPP-server")
        .WithHttpsEndpoint(new Uri(urlFromServer))
        .DisableDefaultEndpoints();

 string GetUrlFromServer() 
 {
      // Get this url from "MYAPP-server"
      return "https://localhost:17061/login?t=4d571ce34e2c5b96ca157179cfe385e8";
 }



Screenshot to show URL which I am trying to change:

If you need any additional information let me know!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/service-discovery/overview
and
https://github.com/dotnet/aspire/issues/3456

Is the real question how to configure dashboard authentication? The URL token is only meant for development. In fact, the Aspire Dashboard itself is only meant for development. If you deploy it on production behind a server like IIS or NGINX you can use the security features of the web server to restrict access only to specific users or groups.

Or you can use OIDC, something that can be configured using environment variables.

The screenshot you posted shows how to restart one of the services, not the dashboard. The dashboard itself will generate a new token when it restarts unless you specify a token again, through an environment variable.

Or are you asking how to use a token for service security instead of proper authentication? That's not a good idea. If you use OIDC in production you'll be able to use it to login to both the dashboard and the web front end.

@FilipFranik thanks I will check it. Looks like on github link there is kind of a similar question, will try to understand and use it.

@PanagiotisKanavos Is the real question how to configure dashboard authentication? - no; The screenshot you posted shows how to restart one of the services, not the dashboard - correct Or are you asking how to use a token for service security instead of proper authentication? - incorrect; The question is how to change/set dynamicly (whenever aspire dashboard starts) url which I've shoved on screenshot.
Please check the updated post, tried to make it more clear
